# Material Design Color for Pre-Lollipop and Lollipop devices doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

I try to run my app on Pre-Lollipop devices. But this code shows me same error for Pre-Lolliop and Lollipop devices.
 If I add "android:"  to the styles like in styles 21 the lollipop device works, but show me some error like the android:color requires Android lvl 21(current Api lvl is 17).

styles

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="imageButtonStyle">@color/icons</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondary">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/icons</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles21

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@color/icons</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/icons</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#4CAF50</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#388E3C</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#C8E6C9</color>
    <color name="accent">#8BC34A</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
</resources>
```

Gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hansbaum.calculator"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+"
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.hansbaum.calculator">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark` and `colorAccent` don't lie in the 'android' namespace. But, the rest of them lie in the android namespace. So, your style(both normal and v21) should like this:

```
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@color/icons</item>
    </style>
```